# SimpleWeather with geolocation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement [SimpleWeather](http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/Idsaj) pluging with geolocation. I tried this code, but it just display the button. I tried the example without geolocation and it's working fine, plus my browser is compatible with geolocation feature.

I'm deploying the file in Tomcat server, any help?

I am also get this console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.simpleWeather is not a function

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/2.5.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="weather"></div>
<button class="js-geolocation" style="display: none;">Use Your Location</button>

<script>
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  $('.js-geolocation').show(); 
} else {
  $('.js-geolocation').hide();
}

/* Where in the world are you? */
$('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude); //load weather using your lat/lng coordinates
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadWeather('Seattle',''); //@params location, woeid
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';  

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that you provided on codepen does not include simpleWheather plugin. Add this to html :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.0.2/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doYemr)

Comment: No, it's permitted for ths site, the problem is that even before to click the button, it should display some random weather but all I can see is a button doing nothing

Comment: @LolaLoulita which browser do you use. your code works fine for me i am using chrome 43.0.2357.45

Comment: and do you get any console error can you check developer console

Comment: I'm having this in the console Uncaught TypeError: $.simpleWeather is not a function

Comment: so you did not added simpleWeather.js to your code i made another pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doYemr